# What determines the number of dolphins chasing my unicorn?

Tags: achievements, ios, robot-unicorn-attack

The "Dolphin Dancer" achievement requires that I get three dolphins to appear on screen.  It seems that the longer I run, the more likely I am to get more dolphins, but I'm curious what actually causes this number to increase.  Is it distance, number of fairies collected, number of stars destroyed by rainbow power, or perhaps some combination thereof?

Comment: I think # of dolphins = score / 5000. like 1 at 5k, 2 at 10k etc

Comment: It's determined by what you've been drinking :)

Comment: @Josh This seems to be borne out by experience.  Make your comment into an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based from my experiences playing the game:

The `# of dolphins on screen = Current Score/5000`
It seems the dolphins reappear after every 5000-multiple as well.

By this formula it would take 15000 score to get 3 dolphins.
Hope this helps

Comment: I have never gotten 15,000 but I have gotten 3 dolphins